# Cannot convert from mts (AVCHD) to mkv using ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, converters, mkv

I was trying to convert a .MTS file from my camcorder (Panasonic HC-V700) to a .mkv file (because my editing software does not support MTS). I used the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i 00000.MTS -scodec copy -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f matroska 00000.mkv
```

But instead of getting a mkv file I get this:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.6-1ubuntu2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-11ubuntu1) 20160311
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu2 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu2 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '00000.MTS':
  Duration: 00:00:07.68, start: 2.306356, bitrate: 12032 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
[matroska @ 0x6ce920] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[matroska @ 0x6ce920] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[matroska @ 0x6ce920] Codec for stream 2 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, matroska, to '00000.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF), 1920x1080
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[matroska @ 0x6ce920] failed to avoid negative pts -65 in stream 2.
Try -avoid_negative_ts 1 as a possible workaround.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[matroska @ 0x6ce920] failed to avoid negative pts -63 in stream 2.
Try -avoid_negative_ts 1 as a possible workaround.
[matroska @ 0x6ce920] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
[matroska @ 0x6ce920] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
frame=   23 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     187kB time=00:00:00.41 bitrate=3705.7kbits/s    
video:707kB audio:7kB subtitle:3kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

Any ideas why is it not working? (I am on Kubuntu 16.04 and I have ffmpeg version `2.8.6-1ubuntu2`.)

(I'm sorry for my English.)

**Edit:**

I tried the command without the subtitle stream (`ffmpeg -i 00000.MTS -c copy -sn 00000.mkv`), conversion failed again:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.6-1ubuntu2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-11ubuntu1) 20160311
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu2 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu2 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '00000.MTS':
  Duration: 00:00:07.68, start: 2.306356, bitrate: 12032 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
[matroska @ 0x1b3a900] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[matroska @ 0x1b3a900] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, matroska, to '00000.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[matroska @ 0x1b3a900] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
[matroska @ 0x1b3a900] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
frame=   17 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     184kB time=00:00:00.28 bitrate=5386.9kbits/s    
video:554kB audio:1kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

**Edit: Temporary solution**

I have found out, that converting to mp4 (`fmpeg -i 00000.MTS -c copy -sn 00000.mp4`) works. This does not solve the issue, but I can use the mp4 format in my editing software as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to keep the subtitle stream, try

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts  -i 00000.MTS -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 00000.mkv
```

Else, just skip it

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i 00000.MTS -c copy -sn 00000.mkv
```

**Edit**: Added PTS gen to work around PTS errors in the source.

Comment: I do not need the subtitle stream, tried to skip it. The output was similar. :/ (I have added the output into my question above.)

Comment: Try now. There's an open bug [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3369) related to the error you're getting.

Comment: Still does not work. :( But there is possible workaround to convert from mts to mp4 and then from mp4 to mkv, if needed. It's not ideal, of course...